# Valadoc with Autotools usage

Tags: autotools, glib, autoconf, automake, vala

I already used [valadoc](https://valadoc.org/) in a standard way using the command line but now my Vala-based project depends on Autotools build system. So I want to know is it possible to use **valadoc via Autotools** and if so how can I make it?

Comment: Too lazy to type out an answer, but there are examples at https://github.com/nemequ/bump/blob/master/bump/Makefile.am#L58 or https://git.gnome.org/browse/gitg/tree/libgitg-ext/Makefile.am#n79 or https://git.gnome.org/browse/gxml/tree/docs/valadoc or many many other places.